# Frame layout getting stuck when I hide soft input (Android)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have an Android app (fullscreen, landscape), and I have two Views, one is a `FrameLayout` that's always visible, and one's a `LinearLayout`. I set the visibility on the `LinearLayout` to `View.GONE` right off the bat. When the user taps a button on the `FrameLayout`, I set visibility on the `LinearLayout` to `view.VISIBLE`, and use the `InputMethodManager` to show the soft input on an `EditText` in the `LinearLayout`. This results in both views being shifted up such that the EditText is on screen just above the keyboard. This is all fine.

The problem arises when I close the soft input. In the same callback, I set the visibility of the `LinearLayout` (with the `EditText`) to `View.GONE`, and what I'm seeing is the FrameLayout getting stuck on top of the screen (it doesn't shift back down). If I don't GONE-ize the `LinearLayout`, both Views shift back down just fine.

I can work around the issue by starting a timer to wait before setting the visibility to `GONE`, but I shouldn't have to do that; there should be some notification that I can receive consistently that will indicate when I can hide the `LinearLayout`.

Things I've tried: `hideSoftInputFromWindow` with a `ResultReceiver` (result receiver callback gets invoked pretty well immediately (i.e. before the keyboard actually disappears), view is GONEd too quickly, same problem), overriding onLayout for the `LinearLayout` (doesn't get invoked when the soft input moves the View up and down), overriding other `View` "on"s.

The other really annoying thing is this problem *seems* to be exclusive to my phone - an AT&T Samsung Galaxy SII Skyrocket running Android 4.0.4 (possibly with some Samsung modifications). I can't repro on a 4.0.3 simulator, nor can anyone else repro on other devices with other Android versions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `View.GONE` have you tried `View.INVISIBLE`? `GONE` reflows the layout and `INVISIBLE` keeps everything stationary. Or do you want everything to shift up?

Comment: I have tried that, yes. I get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to write your own touch event handler. Here is an example that will slide the whole frameLayout view down when the soft input is hidden. As you can see, it is important to call the super handler and wrap our code in a test for textEdit widgets. If you want to get a look at the calculations, uncomment the debugging logger code.

```
    @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    View v = getCurrentFocus();
    boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    if (v instanceof EditText) {
        View w = getCurrentFocus();

        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

        // Log.d("Activity",
        // "Touch event "+event.getRawX()+","+event.getRawY()+" "+x+","+y+" rect "+w.getLeft()+","+w.getTop()+","+w.getRight()+","+w.getBottom()+" coords "+scrcoords[0]+","+scrcoords[1]);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() || y < w.getTop() || y > w
                        .getBottom())) {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    return ret;

}
```

Comment: Heh, the phone in question is out of commission, plus I don't work there anymore, so the problem has effectively dissolved! Unfortunately I have no way of verifying the fix... :(

Comment: I knew that it would not help you solve that problem because it's much too late and I don't have a TARDIS. Perhaps, however another person will benefit from the pain I endured to solve it myself. I'm sure if two of us had the problem, a 3rd does as well.